# EnumType @RequestParam not working on spring

Tags: spring, rest, request, http-request-parameters

So guys I don't what is going on, I need to add an entry to db table. I created an endpoint that needs as parameter an EnumType called ActionStatisticType but Spring can not map it.

This is the way I'm doing the request in angular:

```
 this.httpService.put(this.serviceUrl, actionType)
```

This is the request it creates to backend:

[image]
[image]

This is how I mapped it on spring:

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void create(@RequestParam ActionStatisticType actionType) {
        log.info("#ActionStatisticController.register {}", actionType);
        this.service.create(actionType);
    }
```

And this is the error I get:

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required ActionStatisticType parameter 'actionType' is not present
```

I also tried encapsulating it in an object and setting an attrib name but it didn't work either.

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to provide the name of parameter:

```
@RequestParam(value = "actionType") ActionStatisticType actionType
```

After that you need to try call URL with the parameter, please see the following example:

> https://localhost:8773/webfront/actions?actionType=TEST_ACTION_TYPE